# Is there a version of Linux that looks exactly like Windows?

Tags: windows, linux

I am attempting to help out an unfunded community that would like educate young kids to use computers and since they are most familiar with Windows however do not have the money to buy licenses, is there a version of Linux that is like for like for Windows e.g. rather than display a root directory it displays C:\, etc?

Please note that the community is not a non-profit. It is a simply a large group of people who don't have the money and the computers they are using are donated.

Comment: Is ReactOS stable enough for you?

Comment: @new123456 - To be honest, I have not had a look at ReactOS but having had a quick glimpse at it, it does seem interesting. Will certainly look into it.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you want to look like?  That is, Windows doesn't look like Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a few. The best one, now in its third release, has tried very hard to make looks and function the same as Windows. They have done a pretty good job. Give [YLMF](http://www.ylmf.org/en) a try.

But you need to realize that it is still a Linux-based operating system. Just about anything learned, aside from the handling of the desktop window, will not apply to Windows and will teach nothing about Windows. It will be misleading, to say the least, and the learning will not be transferable when they return to real Windows.

Comment: Fantastic. The intention is to introduce them slowly to Linux. This helps to transition them from using Windows to Linux whilst at the same time educating them on the benefits of open source.

Comment: Only concern I have is that it is a distribution from China not that I have anything against them but how can I ensure that it adheres to the standards adopted by the likes of Red Hat, Suse, Debian, etc?

Comment: @Peanuts it is ubuntu based, so there are some standards backing it i think.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan - How is it in terms of security i.e. backdoors, trojans, etc?

Comment: @Peanuts the majority of viruses that effect windows can't touch linux.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan - I don't just mean viruses but also software that allow unscrupulous individuals, organizations or governments to take control or to snoop, etc.

Comment: Ubuntu has documentation on their security https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't, and there never will be for a strict definition for like for like. There are some technical differences between Windows and Linux which always will shine through.

Comment: Also, there would be copyright problems.

Comment: @Jürgen Strobel - I don't think some differences would be a major issue however was wondering if there was a distribution that is relatively close

Comment: @KCotreau - Why would there be copyright problems?

Comment: I came across a theme that attempts to dress-up Ubuntu to look like Windows - http://ubuntu.online02.com/node/14.

Comment: I also came across http://www.oslike.se/xp-like. Does anyone know of this distribution?

Comment: I answered as harshly because the question was given with a narrow scope. Remapping drive names alone would be a major task to achieve for Linux distributions since drive handling is very different in the unix world. Maybe you should just ask for the most windows-like distribution instead.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey There would be none for you, but for the maker there could be. Appearance of things is usually copyrighted. If I created an interface that looked EXACTLY like Windows 7, how long do you think it would be before I got sued? You would have no issues as a user, but that was just a comment on why there is none.

Comment: Or you ask for the most easy to use linux distribution instead -- often users are put off very much by minor differences, but adapt quite well to bigger ones. My personal advice is to install Ubuntu for beginners, both because it is easy for them and for your.

Comment: @Jürgen Strobel/KCotreau - Thanks guys. Will investigate it further.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Send me an e-mail (address in my profile). I may have some ideas about how to get what you need.